# Como fazer uma filtragem avançada de dados por vários campos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela da qual eu preciso obter resultados variando por certos dados do usuário:

[image: tabela]

Eu preciso retornar as linhas onde cada coluna ou bata com o respectivo parâmetro do usuário ou esteja em branco (null). <sub>Considere como parâmetros do usuário a parte de baixo da imagem - *USER_ID=29*, *USER_GROUP=ADMIN*, etc.</sub>

No caso acima, retornaria somente as IDs 30, 31, 33 e 36.

Comment: Acabei fazendo na pressa a pergunta, pois não queria ter que contar toda uma história da minha situação, sendo que o problema era uma iluminação sobre a lógica de filtragem. 

Usei uma situação mais genérica possível para facilitar o entendimento. Confesso que no lugar de vocês, eu desejaria saber mais a respeito, para minha ajuda ser a melhor possível para situação. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda! Infelizmente não posso dar upvote da resposta do @Caffé, que foi a que resolveu meu problema, muito óbvio :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query abaixo retorna os registros onde cada campo ou é igual ao parâmetro ou é nulo. A função ***find_in_set*** do MySql faz o truque de procurar por um valor em uma lista textual de valores separados por vírgula.

```
select
    ID, USER_ID, USER_GROUP, USER_ROLE, USER_LEVEL, USER_TYPE
from
    tabela
where
    (USER_ID = 29 OR USER_ID is null)
    and (USER_GROUP = 'ADMIN' OR USER_GROUP is null)
    and (find_in_set(1, USER_LEVEL) OR USER_LEVEL is null)
    and (find_in_set(3, USER_TYPE) OR USER_TYPE is null)
    and (USER_ROLE = 10 OR USER_ROLE is null)
```

Veja funcionando no [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29565/13/0).

Comment: Motivo pelo qual não acho a pergunta clara é o facto de estares a assumir que o _vazio_ na imagem colocada na pergunta é de facto `null` em MySQL e não `empty`!

Comment: Para jogar pelo seguro, deveria ser algo tipo `WHERE coluna IS NULL OR coluna = ''`. Mas isto é provavelmente código a mais se soubermos a estrutura da tabela :)

Comment: Não sei a que comentário do @bigown te referes, mas a tua `query` só está correta se os campos forem `null`, porque se estiverem vazios isso falha. `NULL` é diferente de `''`. Mas só estou a alertar, força aí com o sucesso da tua resposta :)

Comment: Obrigado, @Zuul. Estou sabendo deste detalhe da SQL. Estou de fato assumindo que células sem valor sejam NULL no banco de dados, que é a prática mais comum.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente @Caffé! Uma pena não poder dar upvote :(

Answer (score 3):

A query abaixo faz exatamente o que está proposto no enunciado:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM USER
WHERE (USER_ID = 29 OR USER_ID IS NULL)
AND (USER_GROUP = 'ADMIN' OR IFNULL(USER_GROUP, '') = '')
AND (find_in_set('1', USER_LEVEL) OR IFNULL(USER_LEVEL, '') = '')
AND (find_in_set('3', USER_TYPE) OR IFNULL(USER_TYPE, '') = '')
AND (find_in_set('10', USER_ROLE) OR IFNULL(USER_ROLE, '') = '')
```

Você pode verificar o retorno correto no [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/612e00/1/0).

Comment: Na verdade a função *"find_in_set"* faz esse truque de procurar por um item numa lista textual separada por vírgula. Eu havia confundido esta função com o próprio "in" na minha resposta mas agora corrigi.

Comment: @Caffé Obrigado pela dica, esqueço que o MySQL tem tantas facilidades.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Uma pena não poder dar upvote :(

Comment: +1 por ter "jogado pelo seguro" (*IFNULL*) como sugeriu o @Zuul.

Answer (score 2):

Isto está meio esquisito e não tem informações suficientes mas vamos lá.

```
select * from tabela where user_id = $user_id || user_group = $user_group || find_in_set($user_level, user_level) || find_in_set($user_type, user_type) || find_in_set($user_role, user_role) || (user_id = null && user_group = null && user_level = null && user_type = null && user_role)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/Query.php).

Isto funciona se estes campo que podem possuir mais que um valor tiver apenas um dígito.

Eu interpretei as regras como eu pude visualizar na pergunta. Se não é isto você deveria deixar as regras mais claras. Você sequer disse de onde vem essas informações, eu supus novamente. Também supus que o vazio seria nulo.

Answer (score -2):

Creio que seja isso, vou responder em SQL PURO

```
   SELECT * FROM nomeDaTable WHERE USER_ID = 29 OR USER_GROUP = "ADMIN" OR USER_LEVEL = 1 OR USER_TYPE = 3 OR USER_ROLE = 10 OR (USER_ID = "" && USER_GROUP = "" && USER_LEVEL = "" && USER_TYPE = "" && USER_ROLE = "")
```

Comment: Não deveria ser usado o operador `and` no lugar do `or`?

Comment: Essa *query* virtualmente retorna tudo do banco :)

Comment: Dei CTRL C do primeiro pedaço e esqueci de arrumar, vlw aí

Comment: Ela não pegará a linha 36. Se bem que pelas regras aparentes a linha 34 também deveria ser pega e ele não colocou. Se não for isto, só ele sabe quando deve pegar uma linha ou não.

Comment: Realmente, bem observado, se vem a 36 deveria vir a 34 também.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa 34 não porque ela tem *USER_TYPE = 2* e o filtro pede *USER_TYPE = ou contém 3*.

Comment: Eu não sei nem se esses números são apenas exemplos. Minha interpretação é que é apenas um exemplo porque não faria sentido alguém fazer uma *query* em que se sabe exatamente o que vai retornar.